# Ability to show list in KoGrid

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, templating, kogrid

I am using KoGrid to and binding it with some DataArray. It displays all the flat data fine but at the same time one of the object member is an array and I would like to show all the array members in the grid as a list (as bunch of

s). Unfortunately, KoGrid is failing to show any data that is not one to one mapping.

For example, if I have userData= {Name:"",Email:"",Addresses:["",""]} I am using a foreach template to display addresses in the grid. I can go to the firebug and see that the template has produced multiple addresses and feeding it to Kogrid. But KoGrid fails to display that.

I can (in the firebug) change it's koRow class's line-height property and have all the data displayed. I also tried overriding that property by defining that property on my local css but KoGrid always ignores that.

Anyhow, if possible I do not want to be playing with CSS properties. Instead of that, I would like to know that if KoGrid supports any mechanism using which I can display multiple addresses in this case or Array members in general.

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle so we can see what your problem is?

Comment: Hi, so I have created two Fiddles for you to take a look. The first one is simple where I have array as member of my observableArray and it shows all the members as Comma delimited Here:`http://jsfiddle.net/sf4p3/57/`. Second one is more detailed, I am putting up a template on top of it saying whenever you see address Array, put it in bunch of <li> elements. here:`http://jsfiddle.net/sf4p3/69/`. In this one, KoGrid is only able to display first element. Not because template is failing. I have seen it in Firebug that template is working. But because of the line-height and Rowheightare wrong.

Comment: It is all because KoGrid has decided to act rigid on CSS Properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is using the master branch version of koGrid, which is unstable/buggy and has not been released yet. I've found the latest release (1.1) to be pretty good. Using it, your first fiddle (without cell-templates) already shows the array as a list.. Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sf4p3/74/

About your 2nd fiddle.. as you say it's just a CSS issue. You are the author of the cell-templates, hence it's your responsibility to get the CSS right. Here's a simple example of how to do that with your 2nd fiddle (with `display:inline` on the list-items): http://jsfiddle.net/sf4p3/75/